# rails 5 Adding bootstrap and css to collection_select syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

After lot of googling still not getting this solution for adjusting width for collection_select.
I want to set width of my collection_select form so I need help can anyone suggest me where i am doing mistake.
I am getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^~~~~~
```

Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group ">
<%= f.label :Employee, class:'col-sm-3 control-label' %>
<%= f.collection_select(:Employee_id, Employee.order(:name),:id,:name,include_blank: false, {promt: 'Select options'}, { class: 'form-control col-sm-8' , style: 'width:50%'})%>  </div>
```

Any help must appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution my mistake is i am missing { } to include_blank. that comes under the options part 
okay so here is the correct way.
Hope its may help for someone.

```
<div class="form-group ">
<%= f.label :Employee, class:'control-label' %>
<%= f.collection_select( :Employee_id, Employee.order(:name),:id,:name,{include_blank: false}, {class: 'form-control '})%></div>
```